# How can I return symbols based on the sum of lists?

Tags: unresolved-external

So I am new to Scheme and have encountered a problem. What I am trying to do is the following. It's a rather simple problem nevertheless I am receiving several errors:

I try to sum up the elements of lists (which only consists of numbers). If the total amount is even, the procedure should return <'divisible_by_2>.
If the total amount is odd, it should return <'not_divisible_by_2>.

The initial sstep was to build a procedure that sums up the lists. This one works. The second step was to build an if function which takes the sum of lists and returns `<'divisible_by_2>` if the sum is even and `<'not_divisible_by_2>` if it is odd.

What I wrote so far:

```
(define (divisible_or_not list-sum lst)

(if (odd? list-sum lst)
  (lambda (list-sum lst) 
                        (cond
                          ((null? lst)
                           0)
                          ((pair? (car lst))
                           (+(list-sum (car lst)) (list-sum (cdr lst)))
                          (else
                           (+ (car lst) (list-sum (cdr lst)))
                          )         
                          )
                        )
    ('divisible_by_2)
    ('not_divisible_by_2)
  )
)
```

)

Version 2.0 (lst=tree; tree-count=sum-lst):

```
(define (divisible-or-not tree)
  (define (tree-count tree)
    (cond
      ((null? tree)
        0)
      ((pair? (car tree))
        (+(tree-count (car tree)) (tree-count (cdr tree)))
      (else
        (+ (car tree) (tree-count (cdr tree))))))
  (if (odd? tree-count tree)
    ('divisible-by-2)
    ('not-divisible-by-2))))
```

Comment: Please spend some quality time studying the Scheme documentation or course material at your disposal, the syntax in your code is not correct at all, it'll take a complete rewrite to fix it.

Comment: From the description, you should have *two* functions: one that sums a list's element and one that returns different symbols depending on whether its argument (which should be an integer) is odd or even.

Comment: Thanks both to Oscar and molbdnilo! I know that I am struggling with the syntax. Sorry! In version 2.0 I added modifications. I think its better than the first version but it does still not work. Any suggestions why it is not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code, properly indented, looks like so:

```
(define (divisible_or_not list-sum lst)
  (if (odd? list-sum lst)
      (lambda (list-sum lst) 
        (cond
         ((null? lst)
          0)
         ((pair? (car lst))
          (+(list-sum (car lst)) (list-sum (cdr lst)))
          (else
           (+ (car lst) (list-sum (cdr lst))))))
        ('divisible_by_2)
        ('not_divisible_by_2))))
```

The structure of your program looks like this:

```
(if ... 
  (lambda (...) ...))
```

In other words, if your test succeeds, you return an anonymous function, and if the test fails, you return nothing (in Scheme, the value is undefined in that case).

Inside your lambda, the code is a list of three expressions, a `cond`, the form `('divisible_by_2)` and the form `('not_divisible_by_2)`.

First of all, do not use underscores for separating words in Lisp/Scheme, use dashes, like so: `divisible-by-2`.

Secondly, only the last expression's value is returned from the lambda, so the intermediate `cond`, since it has no side-effect, is basically doing work for nothing. The second form, `('divisible_by_2)`, looks like a function call but is going to give you an error. If you want to return a symbol, just quote it, without parentheses: `'divisible-by-2`.

Since you already have an intermediate function, you can associate it to a name:

```
(define tree-count (sum tree)
  (cond ...))
```

I named it `tree-count` because you also recurse into the `car` of your lists.

Once you have this function, you only need to apply it:

```
(if (even? (tree-count tree))
    'divisible-by-2
    'not-divisible-by-2)
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot @coredump for your support. I rewrote the procedure. First defining the overall procedure (divisible-or-not lst), then defining (tree-count) and the if-function to return 'divisible-by-2 if the sum of tree-count is even. This is what I came up with. I wonder why it does still no work:

Comment: (define (divisible-or-not tree)
  (define (tree-count tree)
    (cond
      ((null? tree)
        0)
      ((pair? (car tree))
        (+(tree-count (car tree)) (tree-count (cdr tree)))
      (else
        (+ (car tree) (tree-count (cdr tree))))))
  (if (odd? tree-count tree)
    ('divisible-by-2)
    ('not-divisible-by-2))))

Comment: I edited my original post. See Version 2.0. I appreciate any help and suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use an editor that highlights where parentheses end (Emacs, Vim, Gedit, or even repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/WealthyBulkyCamel). As it is now, you have an "else" clause inside another cond clause, and you still put parentheses around `divisible-by-2` but not around function application: `(odd? tree-count tree)` is trying to call odd? with two arguments, that's not how it work. You should also call `tree-count` *outside* its definition, that's another parentheses problem. You really need to use an editor that make those errors easy to spot. Good luck.

Comment: Cheers Coredump! I just solved the problem. Slowly, but surely... And for the future I will use an editor. Thank you very much for the useful advice.